# Node.js program is extracting the uploaded zip file but not reading the files after extracting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express server where I am uploading zip files through multer, and when I make the post request I want the zip file to be extracted. At the same time, I want to read the extracted files and return data from them. It extracts the zip file but does not read them.

```
app.post('/', upload.single("dataFile"), function (req, res) {
    const unZipped=new AdmZip(foldername+"/"+req.file.filename)#targeting the uploaded zip file
    unZipped.extractAllTo(foldername)#extracting the file
    var followersArray = [];
    var followingArray = [];
    const jsonString = fs.readFileSync("uploads/"+foldername+"/followers_and_following/followers_1.json", "utf-8") #reading the extracted files
    var array = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        followersArray.push(array[i].string_list_data[0].value)
    }
    const jsonString2 = fs.readFileSync("uploads/"+foldername+"/followers_and_following/following.json", "utf-8");
    var followingObj = JSON.parse(jsonString2);
    for (var j = 0; j < followingObj.relationships_following.length; j++) {
        followingArray.push(followingObj.relationships_following[j].string_list_data[0].value)
    }
    followingArray = followingArray.filter(val => !followersArray.includes(val));
   
    res.send(followingArray)
})
```

I have tried to extract the files in an asynchronous function but it still does not work.

Comment: You probably need to extract the files in a _synchronous_ way, otherwise you may be trying to read from the files that haven't finished being extracted.

Comment: @kjsmita6 How can I do that?

Comment: Looking at the code for the adm-zip library, extractAllTo runs synchronously, so I'm not sure that's the issue here.

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to read from the correct path? You extract the file to `foldername`, but then you're trying to read the files from `"uploads/" + foldername `.

Comment: I have tried to read from "uploads/"+foldername  , foldername+"/followers_and_following  and also "followers_and_following/followers_1.json" all these three. But nothing works. @alphaloop

Comment: And my app.js is in the root directory where I have uploads folder for uploading the file then extracting the file file in the foldername folder. so the path should be uploads/foldername i guess.